# How to fetch information for a "subscription canceled" from PayPal API - GetTransactionDetails

Tags: paypal

I'm having a hard time to fetch more details about a cancelled subscription.
Based on: `GetTransactionDetails (PayPal Docs)` they ask for `transactionID`.

When u fetch the transactions from `TransactionSearch` for a cancelled subscription you get: `[L_TRANSACTIONID48] => S%2d4K459417EN165371R`

If I do a request on that ID I get an error:

> [L_LONGMESSAGE0] => The transaction id is not valid

[error-screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP5Ne.png)

I tried encoded, decoded, nothing works. Is there a way for this or not really?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no API for retrieving the subscription (S-XXX) profile details. The only way to check in PayPal account.

Comment: So basically my only way is to save the cancelled record in a database and then search for a previous record that matches the actual subscription and fill the info for the customer from there.

Comment: I'm importing all the PP transactions for a specific item, so I get the initial sale + rebills + refunds but I can't get the cancel record.